# Attribute not geting set through function

Tags: jquery

I have the following function from that I am setting an attribute of select tag which have sortBy id but its not working from this function i have given alert in this function after setting attribute but its giving null value.

Please Help Me.

```
function getXmlByPrice(mi,mx)
{

    if(mi!="" && mx!="")
    {
        $("#min").text(mi);
        $("#max").text(mx);

        $("#sortBy").attr('onchange','getDataFromXmlByStar();');
        alert($("#sortBy").attr('onchange'));

        getDataFromXmlByStar();

    }
    else
    {
        getXml();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are trying to add an `onchange` handler, instead of

```
$("#sortBy").attr('onchange','getDataFromXmlByStar();');
```

do this:

```
$("#sortBy").on('change',function{
    getDataFromXmlByStar()
});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$("#sortBy").attr('onchange','getDataFromXmlByStar();');
```

instead of this

```
$("#sortBy").change(function(){
    getDataFromXmlByStar();
});
```

Comment: If you wanna set a function to `change` event you have to use that notation. I think you have another problem.

Answer (score 2):

To set an event handler on an element you cannot just set the `onchange` attribute, you need to assign an event handler. Try this:

```
$("#sortBy").change(getDataFromXmlByStar);
```